# LiveData setValue is not working after doOnComplete android RXJava

Tags: android, rx-java2, scheduler, android-livedata

I have a Completable observable and I'm using doOnComplete() operator for updating my events. But when i am updating the livedata using `setValue` its not working replacing with `postValue` is working for me.

Can anyone please help me why `setValue` is not working even after tried setting the scheduler to main thread.

```
Completable.complete()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).observeOn(AndriodSchdulers.mainThread())
                .delay(getApplication().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.one_minute_time_in_millisec), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .doOnComplete(() -> liveData.setValue(some value))
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: getting exception when using setValue

Comment: please let me know if it worked ...

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, which was very tricky. The problem is being caused by the `delay` operation:

```
/**
* Delays the emission of the success signal from the current Single by     the specified amount.
* An error signal will not be delayed.
*
* Scheduler:
* {@code delay} operates by default on the {@code computation} {@link Scheduler}.
* 
* @param time the amount of time the success signal should be delayed for
* @param unit the time unit
* @return the new Single instance
* @since 2.0
*/
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.COMPUTATION)
public final Single delay(long time, TimeUnit unit) {
    return delay(time, unit, Schedulers.computation(), false);
}
```

As it says in the documentation, the delay switch by default to the computation thread. So, with the `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` placed at the beginning you are setting the thread to be the UI thread, but then down in the chain the delay operation changes it back to the computation thread. Therefore, the solution is very simple: put the `observeOn` after the `delay`.

```
Completable.complete()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(() -> mutableLiveData.setValue(true));
```

[You can also checkout this medium post about it](https://medium.com/@dbottillo/rxjava-a-story-about-delay-and-schedulers-a5afc6e5c7fc)